# MongoDB Notification in Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with Python web application. I want to know notification from mongodb whatever i changed in mongodb. i am using the code:

```
from pymongo import Connection
import time
MONGO_CONNECTION = MongoClient(settings.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL+"/"+settings.MONGO_DATABASE['NAME'], safe=True, j=True)
MONGO_DB = MONGO_CONNECTION[settings.MONGO_DATABASE['NAME']]
collection = MONGO_DB["id_64"]
cursor = collection.find(tailable=True)
while cursor.alive:
    print "inside"
    try:
        doc = cursor.next()
        print "new doc"
        print doc
    except StopIteration:
        time.sleep(1)
```

And i am getting the error:

```
OperationFailure: database error: Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=scisphere.orgid_64 limit=0 skip=0
Tree: $and
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 tailable cursor requested on non capped collection
```

So help me what is the wrong i am doing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[MongoDB 3.6](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-3.6) supports `$changeStream` feature to watch changes on a collection.

For example using PyMongo compatible with MongoDB 3.6:

```
   for change in db.collection.watch():
       print(change)
```

The ChangeStream returned automatically resumes when it encounters a potentially recoverable error during iteration. The resume process is transparent to the application and ensures no change stream documents are lost.

Another example to watch all inserts that are happening on a collection using [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/):

```
    try:
        for insert_change in db.collection.watch(
                [{'$match': {'operationType': 'insert'}}]):
            print(insert_change)

    except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:

        # We know it's unrecoverable:
        log.error('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at the above, specifically

```
    try:
        for insert_change in db.collection.watch()
```

`db` IS the database name and `collection` IS the collection name. They are not variables. If you're wanting to abstract your code to use variables for the database / collection you'll need something like

```
mongoConnection[database][collection].watch()
```

eg

```
for database, collections in config['mongo']['dbCollections'].items():
  for collection in collections:
    with mongoConnection[database][collection].watch(resume_after=resume_token) as stream:
```

Comment: Can you explain how to configure it ?
I tried:
```
watch_collections = CONF['databases']["mongo"]["WATCH"]

for collection in watch_collections:
     for insert_change in db.collection.watch()
```
but didn't work for me

Answer (score -2):

import pymongo
from pprint import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict
import collections
from operator import itemgetter

c=pymongo.Connection("mongodb://enter your ip address")

username='learning'
password='************'

c['learning'].authenticate(username,password)
print "connection created"
db=c['learning']
collection=db['order_info']

cursor=collection.find()

print"\n*********************Display Database*****************************"

for document in cursor:
    pprint(document)

Comment: I hope this will be helpfull