# Is there an efficent way to recieve data updates for my python application?

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, api

I'm building Nodejs RestAPI and a Python GUI application, and I want to know if there is an efficient way to receive updates to the application upon changes in the Database (MongoDB)

I have thought about sending API requests every few seconds and check if there are any changes but I suppose it's not good on large scale implementation.

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238183/mongodb-notification-in-python

Comment: @rusu_ro1 Thanks  , `$changeStream` looks like just what I needed, but my question is what next ? how can I send the data to the Python application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238183/mongodb-notification-in-python) was useful

regarding your question: "how can I send the data to the Python application ?"

from [MongoDb manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)

> Change streams allow applications to access real-time data changes without the complexity and risk of tailing the oplog. Applications can use change streams to subscribe to all data changes on a single collection, a database, or an entire deployment, and immediately react to them. Because change streams use the aggregation framework, applications can also filter for specific changes or transform the notifications at will.

so basically your app is "forever" waiting and receiving immediately data once you have changes/ new data